# Is there a way I can count if the number of occurrences of semicolon in a string is more than two in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to do a check to count the number of times a ":" appears in a string. Already I have this code:

```
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entryTrimmed) ||
            isAvailable != null ||
            entryTrimmed.StartsWith("::") ||
            entryTrimmed.EndsWith("::")) ||
            entryTrimmed.
        {
            OK_Button.IsEnabled = false;
            return;
        }
```

Is there a simple way that I could also include where there are more than three ":"?

Comment: try linq with this logic

Comment: Do they have to be together? Currently your code only looks for colons at the start or end. Just `entryTrimmed.Count(c => c == ':')` will tell you how many colons are in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple linq's count:

```
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entryTrimmed) ||
        isAvailable != null ||
        entryTrimmed.StartsWith("::") ||
        entryTrimmed.EndsWith("::")) ||
        entryTrimmed.Count(c => c == ':') > 3 // there are more than three ":"
    {
        OK_Button.IsEnabled = false;
        return;
    }
```

If you don't want to use linq, you can use `Replace` and `Length`:

```
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entryTrimmed) ||
        isAvailable != null ||
        entryTrimmed.StartsWith("::") ||
        entryTrimmed.EndsWith("::")) ||
        entryTrimmed.entryTrimmed.Length - entryTrimmed.Replace(":", "").Length > 3 // there are more than three ":"
    {
        OK_Button.IsEnabled = false;
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use count method

```
var colonCount = entryTrimmed.Count(e => e == ':')
```